# Shuffling an array using random numbers

Tags: java, shuffle

My program runs sometimes, but other times it runs infinitely because the random number generator keeps generating the same number again and again.

```
public static String[] shuffleElements(final String[] elements) {
    String[] shuffledArray = new String[elements.length];
    Set<Integer> generatedIndices = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i < elements.length; i++) {
        int index = -1;
        do{
            index = r.nextInt(elements.length);
            System.out.println(i + ", " + index);
        }while(index == i || generatedIndices.contains(index));
        generatedIndices.add(index);
        assignments[i] = elements[index];
    }
    return shuffledArray;
}
```

How do I fix this problem? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use Collections.shuffle?

Comment: Coding is fun, but research is often more productive. Assuming this is an academic exercise, I'd recommend reading about the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which has been around for ~50 years.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Yes, I've been reading about the Fisher-Yates shuffle, but I just wanted to see if I could come up with something myself. Can you please point out why my program doesn't work? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: If you want to improve this algorithm with a minimum of changes, you could try to keep a list of unassigned indices and generate each index like this: "index = r.nextInt(elements.length - generatedIndices.size())"

Comment: Thank you sstendal. I will try that. Do you know why the program goes on an infinite loop?

Comment: Also, how do I make sure that no element remains in the same index as in the input array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a very simple shuffling of elements using the [`Collections#shuffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method.

```
public static String[] shuffleElements(final String[] elements) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(elements);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return (String[]) list.toArray();
}
```

This method uses the default source of randomness. But if you want to specify your own source for the randomness, you can do so by using this overloaded [`Collections#shuffle(list, random)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(elements));
```